# Git rebase conflict: many files deleted locally, and modified on remote. How to `git rm` all of them?

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I'm on branch **feature** and rebasing onto **master** and histories have diverged. In **feature** dozens of files have been deleted that have at the same time been modified on **master**.
I'm sure I don't need these files anymore, so rebase, keeping what's on **feature**:

`git rebase -Xtheirs master`

It accepts all the changes I did on **feature** but still leaves conflicts for modified files from **master** that have been deleted on **feature**, reporting:

`CONFLICT (modify/delete): some/file1 deleted in HEAD~3 and modified in master. Version master of some/file1 left in tree.`

And

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by them: some/path/file1
        deleted by them: other/path/file2
        deleted by them: another/path/file3
        ...
```

And there's a gazillion of them. I have to run `git rm some/path/file1` for each of them. Is there an easy way to list all the *deleted by them* files and pass them to `git rm` automagically?

**Update:**
If you want to try it out, here's a very small sample GitHub repo with that situation. Clone and checkout feature, then try to rebase onto master.

```
git clone https://github.com/chhh/git-rebase-conflict-resolution
git checkout feature
git rebase -Xtheirs master
```

Comment: There may be an easier way than this, but: start with `git ls-files --stage`. Each file that is "deleted by them" has a stage 1 entry and a stage 2 entry but no stage 3 entry. Read through the list (with awk or python), find such names, pass them to `git rm` (perhaps via xargs).

Comment: @torek thanks for the hint, that `git ls-files --stage` was what I was looking for! The final answer: `git ls-files --stage | awk -v stage=3 -v path=4 '$stage == 2 {print $path}' | xargs git rm`

Comment: Be careful with that command: files will exist in *all three* stages when there's a normal everyday conflict. (Your `-Xtheirs` means there won't be any such conflicts, but if anyone tries to generalize that awk command, it may be painful.)

Comment: The assumption here was that it's a rather common situation when you're the only one using a repo. You commit from machines having forgotten to pull first, and then you're sure that you only want stuff from the feature branch and don't care about the conflicts. Here's a sample repo of that situation: https://github.com/chhh/git-rebase-conflict-resolution

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** oneliner:

`git ls-files --stage | awk -v stage=3 -v path=4 '$stage == 2 {print $path}' | xargs git rm`

---

Answering my own question, thanks to the comment to the original question by @torek.

`git ls-files --stage` will list the *deleted by them* files as having *stage == 2*.
Thus, using `awk` and `xargs`, the full one liner to invoke `git rm` on all of them is:

`git ls-files --stage | awk -v stage=3 -v path=4 '$stage == 2 {print $path}' | xargs git rm`

Run it without the final xargs first to check out what files are gonna be deleted.

**Try it yourself**

Here's a very small sample GitHub repo with that situation. Clone and checkout feature, then try to rebase onto master.

```
git clone https://github.com/chhh/git-rebase-conflict-resolution
git checkout feature
git rebase -Xtheirs master
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only conflicts you have are unmerged paths "deleted by them" I think just `git add -u` will solve the situation.